# How can I increase my performance with Eigen? (sample code included)

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there anything overly inefficient with my matrix math in the following function? I have optimizations enabled in visual studio, and am building in 64 bit release mode. I am feeding rather large matricies through here(750X350), but my performance seems slow none-the-less.

```
void NeuralNetwork::backward(Eigen::MatrixXf back, float learningRate)
{
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf> dedw;
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf> delta;

    int nLayers = layers.size();

    int dIt = 0;
    for (int i = nLayers -1;i > 0; i=i-1)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXf deltai;
        logger->LogVerbose("--------","Back", i,"---------");
        if (i == (nLayers - 1))
        {
            deltai.noalias() = back.cwiseProduct(dSigmoid(X[i]));
            delta.push_back(deltai);
            dIt++;

        }
        else
        {
            logger->LogVerbose("W", i);
            deltai.noalias() = (W[i].transpose() * delta[dIt - 1]).cwiseProduct(dSigmoid(X[i]));
            delta.push_back(deltai);
            dIt++;
        }
        Eigen::MatrixXf dedwi;
        dedwi.noalias() = delta[dIt - 1] * X[i - 1].transpose();
        dedw.push_back(dedwi);
        logger->LogVerbose("dedw", dIt - 1, dedw[dIt - 1]);

        Eigen::MatrixXf WiNew;
        WiNew.noalias() = W[i - 1] - learningRate * dedw[dIt - 1];
        W[i-1] = WiNew;
        logger->LogVerbose("W", i - 1);
        logger->LogVerbose(W[i - 1]);

        Eigen::MatrixXf BiNew;
        BiNew.noalias() = B[i - 1] - learningRate * delta[dIt - 1];
        B[i-1] = BiNew;
        logger->LogVerbose("B", i - 1);
        logger->LogVerbose(B[i - 1]);


    }
}
```

Comment: IO logging in a loop is usually bad for performance.

Comment: Obvious initial question: are you compiling your code with optimizations enabled or not? Debug build or release build? Most compilers do unoptimized debug builds by default, and enabling optimization can often result in improvements of performance by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! probably should've mentioned that the logger verbosity is set to 0. Meaning none of those logs are actually being printed and can effectively be ignored.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am building in 64 bit release mode, and have optimizations turned on. But from what I can tell it is not making a difference one way or the other. Perhaps release mode automatically adds the /O2 flag?

Comment: @Michael "Perhaps release mode automatically adds the /O2 flag" - ehh, yes, that's kind of what a release build *is* - a build with optimizations enabled (for MSVC, the `/O2` flag or similar).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh, I see. Thank you

Comment: Have you profiled your code to determine where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Try to replace your vector<matrixxf> with std::vector<Eigen::matrixxf,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::matrixxf>

Comment: Also, did you use eigen_make_new_aligned macro in your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid memory-intensive operations in performance-sensitive code.

1. Never pass "big arguments" by value.

For instance

```
void NeuralNetwork::backward(Eigen::MatrixXf back, float learningRate)
```

should probably be

```
void NeuralNetwork::backward(const Eigen::MatrixXf& back, float learningRate)
```

This avoids copy-constructing the parameter again and again in the function.

2. Avoid copying inside the function. You push to `delta` and `dedw` vectors matrices that are temporary. You probably want to move them like this: `delta.push_back(std::move(deltai));`
3. Reuse allocated memory. You can probably reuse `delta` and `dedw` workspace vectors. Even if to minimize the unnecessary allocations-deallocations. If you don't need the elements from the previous call -- simply clear them.

These would be the first things to do. And finally -- *profile*!

I would use `perf record` to analyze the bottlenecks in the program. The best way to squeeze out more performance is by fixing the biggest bottlenecks. At this point you don't know where you biggest bottleneck is. So profile, profile, profile.

Comment: "The best way to squeeze out more performance is by fixing the biggest bottlenecks" - Well, I sort of agree, but not really, profiling comes *after* doing algorithmic improvements. The *biggest* improvements usually come from picking a better and more efficient algorithm to solve your problem. But, after doing that; I agree with you.

Comment: Profiling always comes first. Before doing improvements as well as after doing improvements. You won't have any quantitative data to judge that the change was "an improvement" otherwise. That being said, I do not rule out algorithmic improvements. In fact, "fixing bottlenecks" might well necessitate just that.

Comment: "Profiling always comes first ... You won't have any quantitative data to judge that the change was an improvement otherwise." - Good point. Agreed. I think I misread your comment a bit. We do agree 

Comment: I just want to add, Eigen can handle const ref's in a funny manner -- they have a page on writing functions to accept Matrices as arguments. Specifically, the `Eigen::Ref` class may be required here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. These suggestions helped out a lot! Took a little while for me to figure out how to profile my code in Visual studio because It is actually a swig python extension, but it was time very well spent!